# The tag synonym [operator] should point to [operators], not [operator-keyword]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request, burninate-request

[While looking for questions to retag to `operator-precedence`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182085/the-priority-tag-is-ambiguous), I noticed that [operator](/questions/tagged/operator) is currently a synonym of [operator-keyword](/questions/tagged/operator-keyword), which is really a tag about operator *overloading*. **This is really confusing, because people tagging their questions [operator](/questions/tagged/operator) often meant to use [operators](/questions/tagged/operators)**.

This has led to the situation where many of the questions in the [operator-keyword](/questions/tagged/operator-keyword) tag aren't really about any `operator` keyword at all, but rather about the use of operators.

The synonym [operator](/questions/tagged/operator) should be changed to point to [operators](/questions/tagged/operators) instead.

Also, after fixing the wrongly tagged [operator-keyword](/questions/tagged/operator-keyword) questions it would probably not be a bad idea to get rid of the [operator-keyword](/questions/tagged/operator-keyword) tag altogether. As far as I can see, there is no reason to differentiate it from the [operator-overloading](/questions/tagged/operator-overloading) tag.

---

For reference, here are the relevant tag wiki excerpts:

- [operators](/questions/tagged/operators) (2,328 questions)

  > Operators are symbols that occur in nearly all programming and coding languages, for performing calculations and comparisons on data.
- [operator-keyword](/questions/tagged/operator-keyword) (735 questions)

  > In several languages, the operator keyword is used to identify methods which will be used in operator overloading.
- [operator-overloading](/questions/tagged/operator-overloading) (2,313 questions)

  > Operator overloading is a feature of a programming language that allows custom implementations for operators depending on the types of the operands involved. Some languages allow new operators to be defined while others only allow redefinition of existing ones.

Comment: Phew, that was a lot of "operator".

Comment: "Was" being the operative word?

Comment: [Operator operator operator operator operator operator operator?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_satiation)  `</noise>`  +1, but on the other hand, the concept of a `operators` tag being a worthwhile thing kind of irritates me.  It strikes me as excessively generic.